# Julia: Is it possible to transform `fn(df, @macro1 :a, :b, :c)` into `fn(df, (:a, :b, :c)...)`

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

For example, I would like to write a macro `@macro1` that transforms

`transform(df, @macro :X :Y)` to

`transform(df, (:X, :Y)...)`

Heres' my attempt

```
macro macro1(ex...)
    println(ex)
    :($ex...)
end

transform(df, @macro1 :X :Y)
```

This seems quite hard. However, if allow the macro to be on the outside like this

`@macro transform(df, (:X :Y))`

then it's easier. But I am not sure if the "inside" macro style can achieve this.

Comment: What's the point, though? Is this part of something more complicated?

Comment: Yes it is. Much more complicated

Comment: See my edit. The previous version worked only accidentially in this special test case: you must avoid the varargs variant, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you trying to get it working with the comma?

```
julia> macro splicing(expr)
           return Expr(:(...), esc(expr))
       end
@splicing (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand tuple(:w, @splicing :x, :y)
:(tuple(:w, (:x, :y)...))

julia> tuple(:w, @splicing :x, :y)
(:w, :x, :y)
```

The subtle part is that the syntax `@m a, b` is parsed as `@m((a, b))`.  We can just directly wrap this into the splice call.

Don't try this with actual varargs, though, nasty stack overflows can occur.

You might need a special case for input of size one, since this does not construct a tuple:

```
julia> tuple(:w, @splicing :x)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
  iterate(::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:600
  iterate(::Core.SimpleVector, ::Any) at essentials.jl:600
  iterate(::ExponentialBackOff) at error.jl:218
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[34]:1
```

The following could work, but may turn out fragile:

```
macro splicing3(expr)
    if Meta.isexpr(expr, :tuple)
        return Expr(:(...), esc(expr))
    else
        return esc(expr)
    end
end
```